# What is the update on the ILC (International Linear Collider)?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, soft-question, accelerator-physics

Has the project been cancelled? There have been no further talk on the topic for a while.

Comment: See [this website](http://www.linearcollider.org/ILC/What-is-the-ILC/Status-of-the-project)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort and is not actually a question about physics, but about the status of a specific project.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking an actual physics question, but about a status of a future project. This latter is better asked in e.g. the Phys.SE hbar chat room.

Comment: The design is in an advanced study phase although some challenges remains. The project has not been cancelled, but it is waiting for inputs from the community and from the Japanese government as Japan will be the hosting country. In the meanwhile the EuroXFEL, which is not only an outstanding machine, but also an ILC technology demonstrator, is being constructed in Hamburg. So yeah, the topic is not hype at the moment, but things are moving on.